# must be convertible to buffer, not ContentFile - python

Tags: python, django

I retrieving image from remote url:

```
the_result = urllib.urlretrieve(filename)
```

then I want to save image:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

result_image = open('testimage.jpg','wb+')
result_image.write(ContentFile(open(the_result[0], 'rb')))
result_image.close()
```

I am getting:

```
must be convertible to buffer, not ContentFile
```

what am I doing wrong?

I tried also:

```
import StringIO
with open(file_dir, 'wb') as result_image:
    result_image.write(StringIO.StringIO(open(the_result[0], 'rb').read()))
```

now:

```
must be string or buffer, not instance
```